A question about elements in formal power series rings
I have a question about elements  in formal  power series rings with infinite variables.
Let $R=\mathbb{Z}[[x_1,x_2,\cdots,x_n,\cdots]]$.
I want to know if $M = x_1x_2+x_2x_3+x_3x_4+\cdots\in R$.
M has infinitely many monomials of degree $2$. Thus I think $M$ may not belong to $R$.
I think every elememt $M$ in $R$ can be written as infinite sums of monimials   in $\{x_i\}$. But for a fixed degree  $r$, there are only finite monimials $m\in M$ that satisfy the degree of $m$ is $r$.
Is it true?
Any help and references are greatly appreciated.
Thanks!

$M \in R$. A formal power series can have any coefficients; it could even contain every monomial with coefficient $\neq 0$.
